# Not getting API response from Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

In my Login component I'm making two api requests. One is for authentication with `JWT` and another is getting data (which are some packs). They are getting called sequentially. I'm also using `Redux` to store the packs (response got from API call). For that I've set all the Actions and reducers. Note that I should get 4 objects in an array as response from the API call. To prevent auto logout on page refresh I've set the `JWT` token in `localStorage` and set that logic in the `initialState` of actions in Redux. But after logging in I'm getting an empty array as response. I'm also getting a 401 error for the second api call. But in `login.js` when I set the `initialState` to `false` I'm getting the response [Here's what the response look like](https://ibb.co/jkhJG7j). But when I set the `initialState` based on `localStorage` it is giving me [This 401 Error](https://ibb.co/PWjMHkQ).

**Login.js**

```
function Login() {
  const login = useSelector((state) => state.login);
  const packs = useSelector((state) => state.packs);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    await Promise.all([
      axios
        .post(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL_API, data)
        .then((res) => localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token))
        .then(() => dispatch(setLogin()))
        .catch(() => console.log("username or password do not match")),
      axios
        .get(process.env.REACT_APP_PACK_URL)
        .then((res) => dispatch(getPacks(res.data.packs)))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }),
    ]);
  };
  console.log(packs);

  if (login.isLogged) return <Redirect to="/" />;
...
```

**login.js (reducer)**

```
const initialState = {
  isLogged: localStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false,
};

const login = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_LOGIN":
      return {
        isLogged: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default login;
```

**packs.js (reducer)**

```
const packs = (packs = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_PACK":
      return {
        ...packs,
        packs: action.payload.packs,
      };
    default:
      return packs;
  }
};

export default packs;
```

**actions.js**

```
export const setLogin = () => ({
  type: "SET_LOGIN",
  payload: {
    isLogged: true,
  },
});

export const getPacks = (packs) => ({
  type: "FETCH_PACK",
  payload: {
    packs: packs,
  },
});
```

Comment: _"They are getting called sequentially"_... no, they're not

Comment: @Phil where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Promise.all()` does not execute promises sequentially

Comment: @Phil could you please tell me what can be done? coz I'm a bit lost here

Comment: also when I set `initialState` to false in `login.js` then It is executing all the requests